# Authentication issue, Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-authentication, python-3.7

Sorry for my English language, I'm from RU.
I'm writing some code (adding information about my clients in a database, selecting this info, displaying it on some pages on my website, and adding the function EDIT for information about clients).

On the page with the full information about clients I'm displaying a link to "edit" information about these clients.

It works, okay, but when I'm wrapping template code around the link to edit:

```
{% if user.is_authentificated %}
    <a href.....>edit</a>
{% endif %}
```

THE LINK IS NOT DISPLAYED, but I'm authorized! (
Going to the admin panel does not require authorization)

Please, tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's just a typo, you should write `user.is_authenticated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to authenticate any user Django provides an in-built method. You can try your code as below:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated  %}
    <a href.....>edit</a>
{% endif %}

I hope it will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `user.is_authenticated` is a read-only always `True` attribute that does not check for any permissions, activity or session validity. If you simply want to check whether user is anon or registered one it would probably be better to use more verbose attr `user.is_anonymous` and therefore `{% if not user.is_anonymous %}` in your template.

You can read more on this topic in [auth docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/).